# Data optimize using MySQL query or javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, lodash

I have these data in mysql.

```
| code | date                | value |
| A    | 2016-04-04 00:00:00 | 0.1   |
| B    | 2016-04-04 00:00:02 | 0.5   |
| C    | 2016-04-04 00:00:05 | 1     |
| A    | 2016-04-04 00:11:00 | 0.2   |
| B    | 2016-04-04 00:12:25 | 0.6   |
| C    | 2016-04-04 00:15:30 | 0.4   |
```

and i want adjust and send a data to json using nodejs/expressjs
with daily, monthly, yearly sum.

First i try this query.

```
 SELECT date, value FROM 'table'
 WHERE code = 'A'
     AND date >= '2016-04-05 00:00:00'
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, "%y-%m-%d-%H") // or "%y-%m-%d", "%y-%m"
 ORDER BY date;
```

this query runs well. but this is wasteful i think.
because repeatedly querying for number of codes.

**Output:**

```
+---------------------+-------+ 
|         date        | value | 
+---------------------+-------+ 
| 2016-04-05 00:01:56 | 0 | 
| 2016-04-05 01:01:56 | 0 | 
| 2016-04-05 02:01:58 | 0 | 
| 2016-04-05 03:01:57 | 0 | 
| 2016-04-05 04:01:58 | 0 | 
| 2016-04-05 05:01:58 | 0 | 
| 2016-04-05 06:01:59 | 0 | 
| 2016-04-05 07:01:58 | 0 | 
| 2016-04-05 08:01:58 | 0 | 
| 2016-04-05 09:01:59 | 0 | 
| 2016-04-05 10:01:59 | 0.009 | 
| 2016-04-05 11:02:00 | 0.007 | 
+---------------------+-------+
```

Can i get all data with one query?

Finally, i want send this form of data with expressjs.

```
[
    A: [{ date: '2016-04-04 00:00:00', sum: 4},
       { date: '2016-04-04 00:01:00', sum: 6}],

    B: [{ date: '2016-04-04 00:00:00', sum: 4},
       { date: '2016-04-04 00:01:00', sum: 6}]
]
```

or this form

```
[
    { date: '2016-04-04 00:00:00', A: 4, B: 4 },
    { date: '2016-04-04 00:01:00', A: 4, B: 4 }
]
```

i've try mysql query, sequelize, lodash.
but i can't find right way.

Comment: What is the result of the `query` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre result is
`+---------------------+-------+
| date                | value |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2016-04-05 00:01:56 |     0 |
| 2016-04-05 01:01:56 |     0 |
| 2016-04-05 02:01:58 |     0 |
| 2016-04-05 03:01:57 |     0 |
| 2016-04-05 04:01:58 |     0 |
| 2016-04-05 05:01:58 |     0 |
| 2016-04-05 06:01:59 |     0 |
| 2016-04-05 07:01:58 |     0 |
| 2016-04-05 08:01:58 |     0 |
| 2016-04-05 09:01:59 |     0 |
| 2016-04-05 10:01:59 | 0.009 |
| 2016-04-05 11:02:00 | 0.007 |
+---------------------+-------+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery to format your date so you can group on it. Example with daily sums:

```
SELECT code, date, sum(value) as value
FROM (select code, DATE_FORMAT(date, "%y-%m-%d") as date, value from t1) as t2 
GROUP BY code, date
ORDER BY date
```

The result:

```
"A";"16-04-04";"0.30000000447034836"
"B";"16-04-04";"1.100000023841858"
"C";"16-04-04";"1.4000000059604645"
```

Comment: Thank you!! It is exact answer to my intention!!